# Android show blurry preview while large image loads

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

I'm developing a gallery in Android whit Glide. When the user selects a image It loads to a preview without any problems (All images are in the device memory), except when the image is to large > (10000 x 7000) then the loading could take up to 5 seconds in some devices...

What I'm trying to achieve now is to show a blurry image while the full resolution load.

```
Glide.with(getContext())
         .load(path)
         .thrumnail(0.1f)
         .into(mTouchImageView);
```

By using this `thrumnail` method all that I manage to achieve was to show  a blurry image after the delay and almost immediately before the full resolution image.

I'm I doing something wrong whit this method? Is there some way to achieve this behavior or other way to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is very large, hence it takes lot of time to process the image and load the thumbnail.

Workaround I can think of is :

1. While you save these images in your gallery create a thumb image as well. So you save a small and large image.
2. Load the smaller image first in the imageview. It will be very quick. Then load the larger image. Till the time larger image is getting loaded the smaller image will get displayed.

Incase you don't have control over saving the image then probably use schedule background service to create thumbimages for you. Hope this helps.